# Dragging on mobile using Carto?

Tags: carto, mobile

We have this large map of United States on our website and we are trying to see it well on mobile. As the map is too large we lose some functionalities on mobile view like dragging.

Is there any possibility to have dragging capability for mobile using cartoDB?

I've changed this property to the code:

```
    map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', {
        center: [36, -96],
        zoom: 4,
        zoomControl: false,
    })

    // Enable drag handlers.
    map.dragging.enabled();
```

But is working just for desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. The method is `.enable()` without the `d`. You can check a working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/9afd730dacf2547c4d66757074e98fd3). It is working on my smartphone (Huawei).